# Bash sed text replace with weird filenames

Tags: bash, sed

I have a list of files in a directory where the files have spaces and ()

```
File1 (in parenthesis).txt
File 2 (in parenthesis).txt
File name 3.txt
```

And on one line in each text file is the name of the file between <short_description>

<short_description>File1 (in parenthesis)</short_description>

I need to modify it to look like this

<short_description>TEST-File1 (in parenthesis)</short_description>

But I can't seem to get it... I can print the filenames out BUT when I try and do the sed command to just replace the whole line with what I want...

```
for FILE in "$(find  . -type f -iname '*.txt')"
do
    sed -i "s/^<short_description> .*$/<short_description>TEST-$FILE<\/short_description>/" "$FILE"
done
```

... this one give me an error
"sed: -e expression #1, char 54: unknown option to `s''"
which I'm assuming means I haven't escaped something but honestly I have no idea what.

Can someone help?
Thank you!

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the given filenames; are they actually paths (with / included)? If not, what's the specific filename it's getting the error on? Note: putting `set -x` before the command will make bash print the equivalent of what's being executed, which might give you a better idea what's really happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say `for FILE in "$(find . -type f -iname '*.txt')"`, the all filenames
fed by `find` are enclosed with double quotes and merged into a long single string which
contains whitespaces and newlines.

> I can print the filenames out

Even if you try to debug with `echo "$FILE"`, it may look as if the filenames
are properly processed. But it is not. You can see it with something like
`echo "***${FILE}***"`.

Then would you please try:

```
for file in *.txt
do
    sed -i "s#^\(<short_description>\)\(.*\)\(</short_description>\)#\1TEST-\2\3#" "$file"
done
```